# Prevent jquery and/or x-editable from parsing string into an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, x-editable

I wish to display a string which happens to be JSON using x-editable, however, it against my wishes converts it into an object resulting in `[object Object]` being displays instead of the string.  How can this be prevented?

```
var object = {a:1,b:2};
var string = JSON.stringify(object);
console.log(object, string)
$('#json').editable({
  type: 'textarea',
  value: string,
});

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="json"></a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/74oux8mw/

A workaround...

```
var object = {a:1,b:2};
var string = JSON.stringify(object);
console.log(object, string)
$('#json').editable({
  type: 'textarea',
  //value: string,
}).editable('setValue', string);
```

Comment: Need to edit individual properties

Comment: @charlietfl  Thanks.  Like the workaround I just posted a few seconds ago?  Just curious, is this a "feature" of jQuery or x-editable?

Comment: Post this as an answer so it'll help future visitors.

Comment: @TheAlpha  I will later if no one posts a similar answer.  I feel silly posting my own answer 5 minutes after posting the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option:

```
var object = {a:1,b:2};
var string = JSON.stringify(object);
console.log(object, string)
$('#json').editable({
  type: 'textarea',
  display: function(val) {
    $(this).text(string);
  }
}).on('shown', function(e, editable) {
    editable.input.$input.val(string);
});
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/74oux8mw/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/74oux8mw/2/)

Answer (score 1):

the simplest solution that worked for me is to place value between `<a>` tags instead into `data-value` attribute